# css clip is not working

Tags: html, css, clip

I tried several different permutations on css position for parent and child.  I have a spritesheet with 3 cells.  I have some old code that uses the background image trick and I'm trying to update it to use clip :rect( )  inside css.    Ideally I'll have a span that controls the display size. and combination of css properties on the image will get the right cell. What am I missing here?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .marketItemImage{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 104px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        img {
            clip: rect("0px 300px 104px 200px");
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="marketItemImage">
            <img src="http://villagegamedev2.appspot.com/client/assets/textures/sprites/plantsSmall.png" />
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you may want to change the clip value to `rect(top, right, bottom, left)`, then change the position of your image to `absolute` so you'll be able to freely adjust its position (`left/top`). You'll then need to calculate the `top/left` accordingly based on the size of the `span` block and the size of your sprite.

Here is an example.

Some basic information on `clip` property can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

```css
.marketItemImage {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 104px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -189px;
  clip: rect(0px, 300px, 104px, 200px);
}
```

```html
 <span class="marketItemImage">
            <img src="http://villagegamedev2.appspot.com/client/assets/textures/sprites/plantsSmall.png" />
        </span>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that a left: -189px is needed.  I was expecting  clip to take care of all that.

Comment: Ok I get it now.  clip rect parameters don't move the underlying image at all. You still have to use css left and top for positioning.